# What happened to the other Autobots?

Tags: transformers

I know Jazz was ripped in half by Megatron. Jetfire, Arcee, and Elita-1 were killed by Deceptions in Egypt. Ironhide and Que were killed in *DOTM*. Ratchet and Leadfoot were killed by Cemetery Wind and Lockdown in *Age of Extinction*.

But what about the others? What happened to Sideswipe, Mudflap and his brother, Wheelie, Brains, Mirage, or any of the Wreckers?

Comment: Your question about Bumblebee's voice box should be asked separately. Asking too many questions at once will get your question closed as off-topic.

Comment: Also, IMHO your best shot would be to look for Transformers Wikis/Wikias. If any of the info you want is available, they'll likely have it.

Comment: @BCdotWEB except I just want the direct answer and not their life story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... There are lot of bots in there and I cannot remember each and every one of them. So I try to provide some insight on the names you mentioned and what I can find about them.

**Sideswipe**

WikiIn Dark of the Moon, Sideswipe's vehicle mode is upgraded into a convertible Corvette. While Sideswipe goes completely unmentioned in Age of Extinction, he may have been killed by Cemetery Wind or Lockdown.

**Mudflap**

Despite the fact that Mudflap was not shown in Dark of the Moon because he was cut from the film, the novelization and comic book adaptions showed that he was killed by Sentinel Prime.

**Skids**

Despite the fact that Skids was not shown in Dark of the Moon because he was cut from the film, the novelization and comic book adaptions showed that he was killed by Sentinel Prime.

**Wheelie**

In The Last Knight, Wheelie survived and joins with the other Autobots in Cade's junkyard.

**Brains**

In Age of Extinction, Brains reappeared, but lost his right leg after crashing into a river inside a Decepticon Ship. His fate in The Last Knight is unknown.

**Mirage**

He is not listed as deceased on Harold Attinger's deck cards meaning that he is alive and escaped Cemetery Wind and Lockdown and was hidden in an unknown location.

***The Wreckers***

**Leadfoot**

In Age of Extinction, he appears in drone video footage, being attacked and killed by Cemetery Wind agents. Cade, who hacks a Cemetery Wind's spy drone, shows the footage to the Autobots, compelling Hound to salute his fallen friend.

**Roadbuster**

His fate is unknown in Age of Extinction.

**Topspin**

In The Last Knight he is seen in Cuba under the protection of Seymour Simmons and credited as Volleybot.

*Source : simply [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Transformers_film_series_cast_and_characters)*